# Why my desktop shortcuts all change back to xx.desktop after open a .docx file or copy a .jpg file to desktop at ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, shortcuts

Like the Screenshots shows, my desktop shortcuts all change back to `xx.desktop` after open a `.docx` file on desktop folder or copy a `.jpg` file to desktop folder in Ubuntu 20.04.

Desktop shortcuts change to a file and without allow launching.

[image: All desktop shortcuts change]

[image: The desktop shortcut change to a file without allow launching]

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome, ist it KDE?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Just the normal ubuntu20.04.